# Reference same element from multiple parent nodes in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

It seems that jquery's `append` method can only move or clone an element, but what I want is to insert it into multiple parent nodes such that any updates to the element will be reflected immediately "from different places". Do I have to use raw DOM maniplulation to accomplish that, or is there some API I've overlooked?

Comment: You mean something like a two way binding? Can you give us some code and more details

Comment: Well, for example, let's say I have a div which displays messages to the user. Rather than create copies of it or move it around to different "current page" divs, I'd like to simply insert a reference to it into multiple parent nodes such that when I switch to the "current page" it shows the "message" element in whatever state it's currently in.

Comment: So you want to clone an element several times and make sure they all look the same when "updates" happen. How would it get updated? And with what? It could be super easy with vanilla js if we knew how the state of the element will change. Until we know more I will vote for React + Redux, since stuff just happens automagically

Comment: are we talking about a single page application or just plain old "click a link, load static content from server"?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] and properly detailed problem description. When you start mentioning switching *"current page"*, the issue can be interpreted numerous ways. Javascript does not maintain state between complete browser page loads

Comment: I don't want to clone anything, and I'm not worried about browser reloads. I just want to update one child div and have those changes automatically appear in multiple places from wherever it's referenced. Suppose you had an animation that's displayed at the top, bottom, and both sides of the page. It would be inefficient to have to update several elements with the same state information.

Comment: The logical thing would be to retain a reference to the animation div and just insert it into multiple parent nodes so that changes to that single element would appear wherever a reference to that element is being maintained. Make sense?

Comment: Would make more sense with an example and better detailed description of objective

Comment: Yeah, please provide an example, I think I'm getting what you're trying to achieve but not quite sure on what to answer yet

Answer (score 0):

Well, after a bit of research and testing, I've finally come to the conclusion that this just isn't (directly) possible. For one thing, the Document Object Model requires that an HTML node maintain a reference to its parent. Second, workarounds such as patching a node's innerHTML property fail because it's implemented (at least on some browsers) as an immutable "native object" of sorts.

Here's an example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
    function demonstrate()
    {
        function InnerHTMLReference(reference)
        {
            this.reference = reference
        }
        InnerHTMLReference.prototype.toString = function()
        {
            return this.reference.innerHTML
        }
        function node()
        {
            return document.createElement("div")
        }
        var
            root = node(),
            first = node(), 
            second = node(),
            echo = node();
        body.appendChild(root);
        root.appendChild(first);
        root.appendChild(second);
        echo.innerHTML = "Is there an echo in here?";
        first.innerHTML = new InnerHTMLReference(echo);
        second.innerHTML = new InnerHTMLReference(echo);
        echo.innerHTML = "Not a chance.";
        var
            constructor = second.innerHTML.constructor.name;
    /*
        Suprise! 
    */
        if(constructor != "InnerHTMLReference")
            alert("Sorry: " + constructor + " != InnerHTMLReference");
    }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body onload = "demonstrate()"/>
</html>
```

On my platform, this shows:

> Is there an echo in here?
>
> Is there an echo in here?
>
> Sorry: String != InnerHTMLReference